# Why do we clip_by_global_norm to obtain gradients while performing RNN

Tags: tensorflow

I am following [this tutorial](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/tutorials/rnn/ptb/ptb_word_lm.py) on RNN where on line 177 the following code is executed.

```
max_grad_norm = 10
....
grads, _ = tf.clip_by_global_norm(tf.gradients(cost, tvars), max_grad_norm)
optimizer = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(self.lr)
self._train_op = optimizer.apply_gradients(zip(grads, tvars),
   global_step=tf.contrib.framework.get_or_create_global_step())
```

Why do we do `clip_by_global_norm`? How is the value of `max_grad_norm` decided?

Comment: Look up the _exploding gradient problem_.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The reason for clipping the norm is that otherwise it may explode:

> There are two widely known issues with properly training recurrent
>   neural networks, the vanishing and the exploding gradient problems
>   detailed in Bengio et al. (1994). In this paper we attempt to improve
>   the understanding of the underlying issues by exploring these problems
>   from an analytical, a geometric and a dynamical systems perspective.
>   Our analysis is used to justify a simple yet effective solution. We
>   propose a gradient norm clipping strategy to deal with exploding
>   gradients

The above taken from [this](http://proceedings.mlr.press/v28/pascanu13.pdf) paper.

In terms of how to set `max_grad_norm`, you could play with it a bit to see how it affects your results. This is usually set to quite small number (I have seen 5 in several cases). Note that tensorflow does not force you to specify this value. If you don't it will specify it itself (as explained in the [documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/clip_by_global_norm)).

The reason that exploding\vanishing gradient is common in rnn is because while doing backpropagation (this is called backpropagation through time), we will need to multiply the gradient matrices all the way to `t=0` (that is, if we currently at `t=100`, say the 100's character in a sentence, we will need to multiply 100 matrices). Here is the equation for `t=3`:

[image]

(this equation is taken from [here](http://www.wildml.com/2015/10/recurrent-neural-networks-tutorial-part-3-backpropagation-through-time-and-vanishing-gradients/))

If the norm of the matrices is bigger than 1, it will eventually explode. It it is smaller that 1, it will eventually vanish. This may happen in usual neural networks as well if they have a lot of hidden layers. However, feed forward neural networks usually don't have so many hidden layers, while the input sequences to rnn can easily have many characters.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. How are we handling vanishing gradients?

Comment: One option is to construct a network where the gradients have norm 1 (or very close to 1). LSTM networks are such networks, and they are indeed very popular. You can read more about it here: https://www.quora.com/How-does-LSTM-help-prevent-the-vanishing-and-exploding-gradient-problem-in-a-recurrent-neural-network

Comment: @MiriamFarber Thanks for your answer. The example used LSTM cell. Does it necessary to use clip_by_global_norm? because LSTMCell proposed to avoid vanishing/exploding gradients.